# Wordpress - Administering users on a blog

Tags: wordpress, accounts

As a wordpress blog administrator, I create the user accounts.

What are the differences between these role types in wordpress?:
Subscriber
Administrator
Editor
Author
Contributor

I want to add user accounts that can write and edit their own blog entries, which role best suites this?

Comment: There is a WordPress StackExchange site winding it's way through the process at Area51. I invite any WordPress users/admins here to check it out and "commit" if you think it would be helpful. I did! http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find this [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities/) on the WordPress site.

From that page:

> **Summary of Roles**
>   Administrator - Somebody who has access to all the
>   administration features
>   Editor -
>   Somebody who can publish posts, manage
>   posts as well as manage other people's
>   posts, etc.
>   Author - Somebody who
>   can publish and manage their own posts
>   Contributor - Somebody who can write
>   and manage their posts but not publish
>   posts
>   Subscriber - Somebody who can
>   read comments/comment/receive news
>   letters, etc.

You'll want to give your users Author privileges.